# rollapply() by n-months

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I am looking for a way to use rollapply to split a series into sequences by n-months. Suppose you have the following:

```
z <- zoo(101:465, as.Date(1:365))
as.data.frame(z)
```

I would like to get a list of vectors (or lists) of index values for each n-months so I can work on the data... Much like the width parameter is implemented in rollapply except the width in this case is variable (depending on the days in a month).

NOTE: would prefer a base-R solution but would be interesting to see other libraries that can be used

Comment: Do you need `split(z, as.yearqtr(index(z)))` and then apply rollapply on the list or `aggregate(z, as.yearqtr(index(z)), FUN = mean)`

Comment: Updated the question because I wasn't aware there is a quarter notion in R. For this problem I would like to roll using n-months.

Comment: @akrun Maybe I'm overthinking it. Please post as a solution.

Comment: It's okay.  I think @G.Grothendieck covered that aspect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. aggregate

If what you are looking for is the processing described by the code in your answer to your question then what you are looking for would be best descrbed as an aggregation rather than a rolling application of a function.

To get the mean of each month, each quarter and each n months use `aggregate.zoo`:

```
myfun <- mean
aggregate(z, as.yearmon, myfun)
## Jan 1970 Feb 1970 Mar 1970 Apr 1970 May 1970 Jun 1970 Jul 1970 Aug 1970 
##    115.5    144.5    174.0    204.5    235.0    265.5    296.0    327.0 
## Sep 1970 Oct 1970 Nov 1970 Dec 1970 Jan 1971 
##    357.5    388.0    418.5    449.0    465.0 

aggregate(z, as.yearqtr, myfun)
## 1970 Q1 1970 Q2 1970 Q3 1970 Q4 1971 Q1 
##   145.0   235.0   326.5   418.5   465.0 

n <- 3
aggregate(z, as.Date(cut(index(z), paste(n, "months"))), myfun)
## 1970-01-01 1970-04-01 1970-07-01 1970-10-01 1971-01-01 
##      145.0      235.0      326.5      418.5      465.0
```

or use `as.yearmon` in place of `as.Date`.  In the above `mean` can be replaced with an arbitrary function.

### 2. rollapply

**a)** If you really did want to roll over n months then create a zoo object `ag` with one row per month and 31 columns filling the extra columns in short months with NA.  Then run `rollapplyr` with a function that unravels the data for each iteration into one long vector removing the NAs that were added at the end of the short months and feeding it into our arbitrary function.

```
n <- 3
myfun <- mean

ag <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, "length<-", value = 31)
rollapplyr(ag, n, function(x) myfun(na.omit(c(t(x)))), fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
## Jan 1970 Feb 1970 Mar 1970 Apr 1970 May 1970 Jun 1970 Jul 1970 Aug 1970 
##       NA       NA    145.0    175.0    204.5    235.0    265.5    296.5 
## Sep 1970 Oct 1970 Nov 1970 Dec 1970 Jan 1971 
##    326.5    357.5    388.0    418.5    434.5
```

**b)** Another possibility is:

```
s <- split(z, as.yearmon(index(z)))
r <- rollapplyr(seq_along(s), n, function(ix) myfun(unlist(s[ix])), fill = NA)
zoo(r, as.yearmon(names(s), "%b %Y"))   
## Jan 1970 Feb 1970 Mar 1970 Apr 1970 May 1970 Jun 1970 Jul 1970 Aug 1970 
##       NA       NA    145.0    175.0    204.5    235.0    265.5    296.5 
## Sep 1970 Oct 1970 Nov 1970 Dec 1970 Jan 1971 
##    326.5    357.5    388.0    418.5    434.5
```

### 3. rollapply with mean

The following work with mean but depending on what your arbitrary function is they may be modifiable to work with it.

**a)** First, create a 2 column zoo object `ag` whose rows are the sum and length of each month and then use `rollapplyr` on that.

```
n <- 3
ag2 <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, function(x) c(sum(x), length(x)))
rollapplyr(ag2, 3, function(x) sum(x[, 1]) / sum(x[, 2]), fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
## Jan 1970 Feb 1970 Mar 1970 Apr 1970 May 1970 Jun 1970 Jul 1970 Aug 1970 
##       NA       NA    145.0    175.0    204.5    235.0    265.5    296.5 
## Sep 1970 Oct 1970 Nov 1970 Dec 1970 Jan 1971 
##    326.5    357.5    388.0    418.5    434.5
```

**b)** Or yet another alternative is to create a complex zoo object `ag3` whose real and imaginary parts are the sum and number of days in each month and the use `rollapplyr` on that:

```
ag3 <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, function(x) complex(real = sum(x), imag = length(x)))
rollapplyr(ag3, 3, function(x) sum(Re(x)) / sum(Im(x)), fill = NA)
## Jan 1970 Feb 1970 Mar 1970 Apr 1970 May 1970 Jun 1970 Jul 1970 Aug 1970 
##       NA       NA    145.0    175.0    204.5    235.0    265.5    296.5 
## Sep 1970 Oct 1970 Nov 1970 Dec 1970 Jan 1971 
##    326.5    357.5    388.0    418.5    434.5
```

Comment: Can you generalize this to an arbitrary function? It sounds like your solution only applies to calculating a rolling mean. I’m interesting in applying a function on a rolling basis.

Comment: I have rearranged the presentation. The first two sections work with an arbitrary function `myfun ` and the last section may or may not work with more than just the mean depending on what your function is.

Comment: Even though I ended up using my answer below, marking this as the answer because I borrowed a lot of ideas that you presented in order to roll my own rollapply. Thank you for a nice presentation!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, I got it right. But maybe that could work:

```
# create data
z <- zoo::zoo(101:465, as.Date(1:365))

# everything you need is cut it by quarter
quarters <- cut(as.Date(index(z)), breaks = 'quarter', labels = F)
# but if you want list of indices, you make them this way
idxs <- split(seq_along(z), quarters)

# to see what you've got
dplyr::glimpse(idxs)
List of 5
 $ 1: int [1:89] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ 2: int [1:91] 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 ...
 $ 3: int [1:92] 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 ...
 $ 4: int [1:92] 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 ...
 $ 5: int 365
```

Comment: What if you wanted to break it by 2 quarters? Or 2 months?

Comment: In that case I would write it as `breaks = '2 quarters'` or `breaks = '2 months'`'

Comment: So what are the acceptable formats for “breaks”. Read the help but it wasn’t much help. I’m going to try this on Monday but I’m surprised it would understand ‘breaks = “2 months”’ to the cut function. I’ll check it out...

Comment: It's `month` and `quarter`, my mistake. From `?cut.Date`: *a vector of cut points or number giving the number of intervals which x is to be cut into or an interval specification, one of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month", "quarter" or "year", optionally preceded by an integer and a space, or followed by "s". (For "Date" objects only interval specifications using "day", "week", "month", "quarter" and "year" are allowed.)*

Comment: Thank you. Will give this a shot on Monday

Answer (score 1):

Ended up rolling my own rollapply() for a zoo object:

**HELPER FUNCTION**

```
   get.months.elapsed <- function(start.date, end.date) {
      ed <- as.POSIXlt(end.date)
      sd <- as.POSIXlt(start.date)
      12 * (ed$year - sd$year) + (ed$mon - sd$mon)
    }
```

**1. FORWARD ROLLING WINDOW:**

```
rollapply.list.date.range <- function(data, num.of.months, FUN) 
{
  dates.list <- index(data)
  seq.list <- sapply(dates.list, FUN = function(x) {
     dt <- as.integer(x[1])
     cur.seq.list <- separate.by.months(dt, dates.list, num.of.months)
     names(cur.seq.list) <- dt
     return(cur.seq.list)
  })

  lapply(seq.list, FUN)
}

separate.by.months <- function(dt, dates.list, num.of.months) 
{
  date.seq.indexes <- sapply(dates.list, function(x) { 
    date.diff <- as.integer(x) - dt
    date.normalized <- get.months.elapsed(as.Date(0), as.Date(date.diff))
    floor(date.normalized  / num.of.months)
  })

  seq.list <- split(dates.list, date.seq.indexes)
  seq.list["0"]
}
```

**2. REVERSE ROLLING WINDOW:**

```
rollapply.date.range <- function(data, num.of.months, FUN) 
{
  dates.list <- rev(index(data))
  seq.list <- sapply(dates.list, FUN = function(x) {
     dt <- x[1]
     cur.seq.list <- separate.by.months(dt, dates.list, num.of.months)
     names(cur.seq.list) <- dt
     return(cur.seq.list)
  })

  lapply(seq.list, FUN)
}

separate.by.months <- function(dt, dates.list, num.of.months) 
{
  date.seq.indexes <- sapply(dates.list, function(x) { 
    date.diff <- as.integer(x) - as.integer(dt)
    date.normalized <- ifelse(sign(date.diff) == 1, -9999, -get.months.elapsed(as.Date(0), as.Date(date.diff)))
    floor(date.normalized  / num.of.months)
  })

  seq.list <- split(dates.list, date.seq.indexes)
  seq.list["0"]
}
```

And then you would call it like:

```
rollapply.list.date.range(z, 3, mean)
```